# How can I create a Hello World app using F# and WPF without XAML?

Tags: wpf, f#

**How can I create a Hello World app using F# and WPF without XAML?**

Specifically, what are the steps to accomplish this?

For example, what files do I need to launch the application?

**[UPDATE]**

I attempted some suggestions and received the following error:

[image]

I verified that the project was set as the startup project.
I am not sure what else I'm required to do.

Comment: Hint - `Library1.fs` - why did VS give the file this name?

Comment: Thank you. I posted the complete answer.

Answer (score 10):

**The first** thing to understand is this: XAML is just a (supposedly more succinct) way to represent an object graph. (incidentally, XAML doesn't need to specify a WPF UI, it can be used for other things... theoretically)

XAML tags correspond to instantiating .NET classes, properties and nested tags correspond (roughly) to object properties. There is no magic beyond that. All XAML does it just create a bunch of objects and connect them together.

For example, this:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton">Click!</Button>
```

would roughly correspond to this:

```
let myButton = Button( Content = "Click!" )
```

(it does get a little more complicated with attached properties, bindings, type converters, etc., but I won't go into all that here)

---

**The second** key thing to know is how to code the entry point. To this end, there are three easy steps:

1. Create `Application`
2. Create `Application.MainWindow`
3. Call `Application.Run`

---

Here is a minimal fully functional application (in the form of an F# script):

```
#r "WindowsBase"
#r "PresentationCore"
#r "PresentationFramework"

open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls

let button = Button(Content="Click me!")
let label = Label(Content="Hello")
button.Click.Add (fun _ -> label.Content <- "World")

let layout = StackPanel()
layout.Children.Add label
layout.Children.Add button

let window = 
  Window(
    Content = layout,
    Visibility = Visibility.Visible)

let app = Application(MainWindow = window)
app.Run()
```

Comment: oops. okay. it's saved.

Comment: A simple MVC approch can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/adicirstei/8252693570dc387b4f24)

Answer (score 1):

To build on the original answer:

**I had to set the project's output library to Windows.**

**I then had to add the STAThread attribute.**

Here's the code:

```
module Temp

open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open System

[<STAThread>] do ()

let button = Button(Content="Click me!")
let label = Label(Content="Hello")
button.Click.Add (fun _ -> label.Content <- "World")

let layout = StackPanel()
layout.Children.Add label |> ignore
layout.Children.Add button |> ignore

let window = 
  Window(
    Content = layout,
    Visibility = Visibility.Visible)

let app = Application(MainWindow = window)
app.Run() |> ignore
```